# About $16$ lines on the del Pezzo surface of degree $4$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

First, let us consider the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \times \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ at three points $\{(0, 0), (1, 1), (\infty, \infty)\}$.

It is a del Pezzo surface of degree $5$, and there are $10$ lines (  $(-1)$-curves), i. e., the three exceptional divisors $E_0, E_1, E_{\infty}$ corresponding to $(0, 0), (1, 1), (\infty, \infty)$, and the strict transforms of the seven curves $x = 0, x= 1, x= \infty, y = 0, y = 1, y = \infty, x = y$.

Next, I want to consider the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}} \times \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ at four points $\{(0, 0), (1, 1), (\infty, \infty), (p_1, p_2)\}$, where $p_1 \neq p_2$.

It sould be a del Pezzo surface of degree $4$, and I found the 13 lines, which are the four exceptional divisors corresponding to these four points, the strict transformations of the rulings $x = 0, x= 1, x= \infty, x= p_1, y = 0, y = 1, y = \infty, y = p_2$, and that of the diagonal line $x = y$.

However, I haven't found remained $3$ lines.
So, my question is

> **Where are these remained $3$ lines? 
>    Can we get the defining equations of them?**

Comment: Besides the diagonal, there are three more curves of bidegree $(1,1)$ that pass through 3 out of 4 blowup centers.

Comment: I have understood! Thank you very much!